# Pulling private GIT repository on a remote build-server

Tags: git, docker, build, repository, build-server

### Background

I have two node.js projects for my websites. Different website. Those websites are using the same core component (colors, graphic elements, ...). All those components exist in 3'rd projects which are shared for my two websites.

The shared project is stored in a private GIT. I added the repository URL to my `packages.json` file. So, when I'm doing `npm install`, it is installing also my shared package.

The shared project containing Angular 8 components mostly.

### The Problem

While running locally, everything works fine. The problem is when committing the websites to the server build. At this point, it stops working because the server doesn't have permission to access the shared private repository.

My build server works with DOCKER and being executing on a remote server.

### Possible solution:

One possible solution, which I don't like, is to store the username and the password of my user on the docker file. Then, when pulling the GIT repo, it will use my credentials to pull the repo.

Of cause that this solution is exposing my username and password in clear text, which is not recommended.

### The question

What is the best solution to solve this problem?

Comment: why not to setup ssh keys-peer ?

Comment: Please explain?

Comment: I mean using ssh keys instead of username/password - if you are using github use this : https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account or search for the right settings from your git provider

Comment: Is this possible to limit the access of the SSH key to the specific repo? Make it read only?

Comment: that depende on what you are working , but gnerally yes that is possible

Comment: Is your private git repository accessible by other networks? Some companies restrict the access by network as well. In that case you'd also need vpn. Best is to consult to maintainer of that private git repository

Comment: pass username and password in env or mapped host ssh key to container